# Swisscom Application Cloud: Will there be a new version of ELK service?

Tags: swisscomdev

Current version of ELK service is 2.1.0. Is is possible to update to a newer version like 6.1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new Elasticsearch service, which will enable you to use the latest versions of the ELK stack components, is currently in the works. There's no release date set just yet, but look out for the announcement on the Swisscom Application Cloud newsletter.